# Question about use of Controllers

Tags: c#, java, model-view-controller, oop, uml

I was given a Use Case for a Quizz Application. The Use Case is only for creating new Quizzes. I am having trouble deciding which design is better:

a)

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/diagram1.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/diagram1.jpg)

b)

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/diagram2.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/shooterpics/diagram2.jpg)

Although this might look like a Domain Model, it is in fact a Class Diagram (I was lazy to put the methods/attribtues in the diagrams :( ).

The idea behind all this is that I have a `QuizCatalog` that has `Quiz`zes. Each `Quiz` has a set of `Question`s, that must be created through a `QuestionFactory`(a `Question` is an abstract class, and `QuestionA`, `QuestionB`, etc are the concrete classes). Each `Question` has a set of `PossibleAnswers`.

The difference in terms of associations between `Design A` and `Design B` is that in the first I am considereing that `CreateQuizController` will simply delegate every task it has to `QuizCatalog`. If `QuizCatalog` needs to do something, it will delegate everything it might need down the hierarchy. This is actually nice, as it seems to reduce coupling.

`Design B`, on the other hand, follows a different philosophy. The associations seen in `Design A` still exist (as a `QuizCatalog` still has `Quiz`zes, a `Question` `PossibleAnswer`s, etc) but now I've made `CreateQuizController` have access basically to every kind of object in the domain it might need to create in the process(I've signaled those kind of associations with `d`). The idea is that instead of asking the `QuizCatalog` to create a `Quiz`, `CreateQuizController` will create a `Quiz` by itself (and if it needs to create Questions for the `Quiz`, it will by itself, the same happening for `Question`'s `PossibleAnwser`s, etc).

### There are 2 things that bother me about `Design A`:

### 1.

If I need to create temporary objects that need to be filled up before being put "in the system" (for example, a `Quiz` is only actually added to `QuizCatalog` after it was filled with all the wanted `Question`s), following this design I'll have to keep them in some place other than the `Controller`.

For example, when I first create a `Quiz`, I'll have to probably save it under `QuizCatalog` without actually adding it to the current collection of Quizzes that is accessible to the rest of the system. I find this kind of behaviour a bit awkward. I find it better to keep those kind of temporary objects in a `Controller`, as if anything wrong happens then the "System" is kept just as it was before, with no problems associated.

The problem is that it makes the `Controller` have to know about almost everything, which might be undesirable. On the other hand, there is no difference in how coupled the rest of the classes in the `System` are.

### 2.

If I am going to use Design A, I actually don't see a big point in having a CreateQuizController, as basically everything can be done by just having a reference to QuizCatalog. In my eyes, it is just delegating all its work to QuizCatalog, so why have it in the first place?

Also, using `Design A`, I'd probably consider `QuestionFactory` to be a Singleton, while if using `Design B` I'd probably just have `CreateQuizController`'s constructor accept an instance of a `QuestionFactory` instead.

---

What are your thoughts about this?

Thanks

PS: Only after drawing the diagrams I noticed that Quizz has 2 z's :( My bad.

Comment: Quiz definitely has only one 'z' :P Although 'Quizzes' has two. English can be pretty weird...

Comment: How does it work at runtime ? We can consider the library how to use it. Maybe the sequence diagram can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the naming I think, the `CreateQuizController` has too many responsibilities. I assume (again from its name), that it can **create** quizzes and **control**  quizzes. What about separating this in two classes, a `QuizFactory` and a `QuizController`?

So if we need a new quiz, we ask the `QuizFactory` to create a new one, the `QuizFactory` would then create a new quiz, use the `QuestionFactory` to create questions and possible answers and we would add the new quiz to the (static) `QuizCatalog`.

If we want to *run* a quiz, we then would select a quiz from the catalog, create a `QuizController` (with this quiz), and the `QuizController` would start the quiz, present the questions and keep the score.

The `QuizController` wouldn't need to know the questions, it would be enough if the quiz offered methods like `getNextQuestion()` and `getPreviousQuestion()` and a method to validate the candidate's answer (so the controller would know the actual question only).

So a **has-a** relation from `QuizController` to `Quiz` would be enough. And in my design, the  `QuizCatalog` would be (like) a singleton and thus static or owned by another top-level class, like some `QuizManager`.

Comment: Actually the idea was that the CreateQuizController would only create quizes (it is not supposed to manage them later). The name came from the fact that it is a Controller (in the sense that it is "upper") and not from the fact that it will later manage quizzes.

Comment: So my question is, how should I make (your) QuizFactory work? Should it know all the objects in the domain and create them, or should it just delegate that kind of work to the Quiz Catalog? Edit: I see you prefer the first one (through the factory). Hmm

Comment: Now that I think of it, I think that what we actually have here is a kind of Builder Pattern, because I to create the Quiz, I have to also create all the questions, and for each one of the questions, all the possible answers. Do I make sense?

Comment: Sounds pomising - just looked the the pizza-example at wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java) and it could be a match or at least a basis for the *quiz creation* part in your design. Introducing a QuizBuilder is worth a try!

Comment: Other question, what should be the job of a Catalog? Just a get for the set of questions it has "inside it"? Or should it also handle adding and removing elements, etc? From what I've seen you say, it seems it definitely should NOT create them, right?

Comment: I'd just implement a sort of registry for quizzes, just basic get, add and remove operations. Maybe some book keeping (last time used, used how many times, avererage score, ...). But creating a quiz is not the registries responsibility. At most it could *own* a (set of) quiz factory(ies).

Comment: i thought the builder pattern is for complex objects with many (optional) properties. andreas is right, the only thing im missing is a quizfactory, which fills the quizcatalog.

Comment: The thing is that in the Use Case, you have a set of steps before actually building the whole quiz. So in that case it does make sense to use the Builder Pattern, imo. But you couldn't know it, as I didn't mention it in the OP.

Comment: cant you just build an options object during these steps and hand it over to your quizfactory? you wont have quiz objects in undefined states then. I see it like this: builder are for complicated objects with many fields (which leads to long and many constructors due to optional elements or undefined states between initialization by setters) while factorys are for object creation which needs multiple steps from different sources. so which fits best?